# PointerProperty for a particle system

Tags: python, scripting, particles, development

Please, I would like to know How to make a pointer property for a particle system.
My goal is having a prop that contains the particle system name and it updates when the particle system is renamed like what happens to the pointer property for the objects.

As an example, I want to add all the particle systems in the scene into a list then once a particle system removed or renamed the list is updated instantly

Here is an example ( this code belongs to @Karan I've just modified it to fit my example)

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

from bpy.props import (
                        StringProperty,
                        IntProperty,
                        CollectionProperty,
                        )


from bpy.types import (
                        Scene,
                        )




class LIST_OT_Action(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ adds an item to the list"""

    bl_idname = 'list.operator'
    bl_label = 'Select an Object Particle System'


    def execute(self, context):

        obj = bpy.context.object
        scene = bpy.context.scene

        # iterate over the scene objs
        for obj in scene.objects:
            
            # checks the p sys
            if(len(obj.particle_systems) != 0):
        
                p_sys_index = 0

                # iterate over the p sys to add it 
                for p_sys in obj.particle_systems:
                    
                    # add list item per p sys 
                    new_item = scene.ID_LIST.add()

                    # set the name ( this is the property i would like to change 
                    # when the particle system renamed that's why I need to link it
                    # with some unique id so I can update absed on that)
                    new_item.name = p_sys.name

        return {'FINISHED'}

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        scene = context.scene
        row = layout.row()
        
        row.label(text= 'Particle System')
        row.template_list( listtype_name="P_UL_LIST",
                            list_id="",
                            dataptr=scene,
                            propname="ID_LIST",
                            active_dataptr=scene,
                            active_propname="ID_LIST_INDEX")
    

class P_UL_LIST(bpy.types.UIList):
    """draws the Reactions list items"""

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        """draw the items into the list"""

        # split the row for to draw the item icon and name and the status bool
        layout.use_property_split = False             
        split = layout.split(factor=0.95, align=True)

        row_l = split.row(align=True)
        row_l.prop(item, "name", emboss=False, icon = 'PARTICLES')

        
class ListProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    # override the default  name property for the list item which carrys the obj name
    name : StringProperty(
    name = '',
    description = '',
    
    )

    # particle sys property    
    ID_LIST_ITEM_OBJ_P_SYS : StringProperty(
    name = 'Particle System',
    description = '',
    default = '',
    
    )



classes = (
    P_UL_LIST,
    ListProperties,
    LIST_OT_Action,
    CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    # register the list propeties
    Scene.ID_LIST = CollectionProperty(type= ListProperties)
    Scene.ID_LIST_INDEX = IntProperty(name= 'index for ID_LIST', default=0)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
    # unregister the list propeties
    del Scene.ID_LIST
    del Scene.ID_LIST_INDEX
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # call the operator to add p sys
    bpy.ops.list.operator()
```

Thanks,
Mostafa

Comment: So you want a custom particle system list but it should link to the original particle system list, which means if the original particle system list changes it should reflect in your custom list.

Comment: @Karan Yes, That's exactly what I'm looking for. That's why I'm searching for a way to have the particle system maybe as a pointer to be able to have a link between them.

Comment: But if both the list should be same then why you need custom list instead use default particle system list

Comment: @Karan because I'm planning to add particle systems from more than one object. Also, I need to have my own and design for the list. I'm just wondering how blender doesn't have a pointer to store the particle systems?

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel


class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout

        if context.object:
            row = layout.row()
            row.template_list("PARTICLE_UL_particle_systems", "", context.object, "particle_systems", context.object.particle_systems, "active_index", rows=3)
        
    
classes = (
    CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks Karan for the code example. Is there a way to get a unchanged id for the particle systems in blender. I've tried pointers but they are change when the object is deleted

Comment: Please, phrase your question properly with code example.

Comment: Sure @Karan I've just uploaded a code example using your example as base.